# How to unzip a file using nant script? Nant unzip task showing some error?

Tags: build, automation, zip, release, nant

I need to unzip some files using nant script. For that I created a build file.

But it throwing some error like this

`Invalid zip file... , Wrong local signature 0X..`

my unzip code is like this

`<unzip zipfile="${filename}"/>`

How can I fix this issue. Any other method is available to do this extration. 
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If the file is invalid, then how can you expect NAnt to extract it? Otherwise, if you are sure it is valid - file a bug with NAnt.

Comment: I can directly extract using winrar or 7zip. It is a valid zip file.

Comment: Then file a bug with NAnt: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=402868&group_id=31650&func=browse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run 7z with the exec task.

```
<exec program="c:\pathto7zip\7z.exe">
   <arg line="e -oc:\temp\extracted_textfiles textfiles.zip"/>
</exec>
```

This extracts the files from textfiles.zip into a folder c:\temp\extracted_textfiles.